# how to transform a key property from an object type into an array type

Tags: javascript

I have a array of two objects.

I would like to transforming each object's key, allocation, from a object type into array type

From allocation: {} into allocation:[]

They content of the array of allocation would be the children of customAllocations

May I ask how to achieve that?

Original array

```
[
  {
    "allocation": {
      "name": "custom",
      "customAllocations": [
        {
          "name": "Developed",
          "weight": 0.75
        },
        {
          "name": "Diversified",
          "weight": 0.1
        },
        {
          "name": "Global",
          "weight": 0.15
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "allocation": {
      "name": "custom",
      "customAllocations": [
        {
          "name": "Developed",
          "weight": 0.35
        },
        {
          "name": "Conservative",
          "weight": 0.1
        },
        {
          "name": "Global",
          "weight": 0.55
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Expected array

```
[
  {
    "allocation": [
      {
        "name": "Developed",
        "weight": 0.75
      },
      {
        "name": "Diversified",
        "weight": 0.1
      },
      {
        "name": "Global",
        "weight": 0.15
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "allocation": [
      {
        "name": "Developed",
        "weight": 0.35
      },
      {
        "name": "Conservative",
        "weight": 0.1
      },
      {
        "name": "Global",
        "weight": 0.55
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Edit:

Please be aware of modifying the actual object. It may have some problem. So may I know how to have a better approach...That's why I found this problem may have more than it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can map the properties like so. However this will mutate the original obj. You can use for example use `_.deepClone(data)` from [loadash](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-clonedeep-method/) to make a copy of the inital obj.

```js
const data = [{
    "allocation": {
      "name": "custom",
      "customAllocations": [{
          "name": "Developed",
          "weight": 0.75
        },
        {
          "name": "Diversified",
          "weight": 0.1
        },
        {
          "name": "Global",
          "weight": 0.15
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "allocation": {
      "name": "custom",
      "customAllocations": [{
          "name": "Developed",
          "weight": 0.35
        },
        {
          "name": "Conservative",
          "weight": 0.1
        },
        {
          "name": "Global",
          "weight": 0.55
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

// this will mutate the actualy obj
console.log(data.map(alloc => {
  alloc.allocation = alloc.allocation.customAllocations
  return alloc
}))

// this will also display the changed result
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Be careful here you are modifying the actual object.

Comment: yes , exactly , you are modifying the actual object. It may have some problem. But thanks for trying... may I know how to have a better approach...That's why I found this problem may have more than it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it meets your needs. Just a little playing on the object and returning your expected data form.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "allocation": {
            "name": "custom",
            "customAllocations": [
                {
                    "name": "Developed",
                    "weight": 0.75
                },
                {
                    "name": "Diversified",
                    "weight": 0.1
                },
                {
                    "name": "Global",
                    "weight": 0.15
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "allocation": {
            "name": "custom",
            "customAllocations": [
                {
                    "name": "Developed",
                    "weight": 0.35
                },
                {
                    "name": "Conservative",
                    "weight": 0.1
                },
                {
                    "name": "Global",
                    "weight": 0.55
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
const newData = []
data.forEach(elem => {
newData.push({'allocation' : elem.allocation.customAllocations})
})
console.log(newData)
```